# npm install does not make the node_modules folder

Tags: node.js

I am trying to follow the [official tutorial of Protractor with Typescript](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.4.1/exampleTypescript).

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-exercise",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.7",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
  "jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "protractor": "~5.4.3",
  "typescript": "~3.8.3",
  "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
  "@types/node":"~13.7.7"
 }

}
```

when i run the npm install i got the below result:

```
npm WARN typescript-exercise@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN typescript-exercise@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.527s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But, there is no `node_mdules` folder in my root category.

**Why** `npm install` **cannot build the** `node_modules`?

Comment: Depending on your node version, there is `npm doctor` command, try running it

Answer (score 0):

As of the error, try removing empty tags from your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-exercise",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "@types/node":"~13.7.7"
  }
}
```

In case you have `package-lock.json` try deleting that and then run `npm i`. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to install a single one of the dependencies and see if the directory is created or if you get some sort of error.The file could be created but not showing properly(you could [test](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shellscript/) from the terminal depending on os with different methods/commands).